# Python class variable delayed outside of its callback function

Tags: python, python-multithreading, rospy

I have written a python script that subscribes to a ROS topic and then goes into a callback function that then calls the test function that returns a list of radii in ascending order by extracting the necessary data points in the topic. This is working correctly, however I would like to access this list of radii throughout the whole class(and outside of it).

I have made it a class variable "self.radii" but the console throws an error saying the instance has no attribute "radii" unless i tell it to sleep using `rospy.sleep(2)` for 2 seconds and then it returns a value. It's the same story if I try to call self.radii within the main function.

I feel as through this is a Python threading issue rather than a ROS issue as the actual subscriber is working correctly there just seems to be a long delay I do not know how to remedy.

If I instead `print(self.radii)` inside the callback function it works fine, with values appearing immediately, but I want to access this variable outside of this.

The code is below. Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import numpy as np
from laser_line_extraction.msg import LineSegmentList

class z_laser_filter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sub_ = rospy.Subscriber("/line_segments",
                                     LineSegmentList,
                                     self.callback)
        rospy.sleep(2)
        print(self.radii)

    def callback(self, line_segments):
        self.radii = self.test(line_segments)
        print(self.radii)

    def test(self, line_segments):  
        number_of_lines = ((len(line_segments.line_segments)) - 1)
        i = 0
        radii = list()
        while (i!=number_of_lines):
            radii.append(line_segments.line_segments[i].radius)
            radii = sorted(radii, key=float)
            i = i + 1
        return radii

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('line_extraction_filter', anonymous=True)
    node = z_laser_filter()
    rospy.spin()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with how ROS subscribers work. Your class variable `self.radii` will only be created once the topic which you subscribe to `/line_segments` gets its very first message. After that, you can call on `self.radii` from any other function in the class. When your node starts, the `init` function is the very first thing that runs, so it creates the subscriber, and moves on to your print() statement. Between that time, the topic hasn't published a message yet. When you add the `sleep()` it gave the subscriber time to receive its first message.

What you can do, is initialize `self.radii` to something in the init function, just like you did with `radii` :

```
 def __init__(self):

    self.sub_ = rospy.Subscriber("/line_segments", LineSegmentList, self.callback)
    self.radii = list()
    print(self.radii)
```

Then it will be populated with the correct information as you receive messages.

To check how long it will take to receive the first message on the topic `/line_segments` you can use the following command in terminal to see the rate at which it is being published:

```
rostopic hz /line_segments
```